# Is it possible to have multiple wave windows in ModelSim?

Tags: modelsim

Is it possible to have multiple Wave windows opened in ModelSim simultaneously?

I know it is possible to add multiple "Window panes" in a single Wave window but it's so buggy and un-flexible that is barely useful or productive (or even usable). I need to fit all signals of two instances in the screen but I don't want constant access to both of them, so "Window Pane" is not the best option anyway.

I'm using ModelSim Altera 10.0c, rev. 2011.09

Comment: Is this an EE question?

Comment: @andy-aka why not? It's a question about a feature of digital design software. As I have seen, digital design questions are frequent here. And I can certainly see upvoted questions about ModelSim on the "related" section right now.

Comment: I only asked but, it appears it's more a question about how to make superficial changes to how the software displays things rather than a techy question about EE.

Comment: I get your point. But the question could as well have been "how do I add a second monitor on my oscilloscope?" in a slightly different context, which I think would fit perfectly in EE then :)

Comment: 2nd monitor on an oscilloscope is not an EE question methinks - questions on this are not on topic - there's a link somewhere - I'll see if i can find it.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - note that I have not opted to close your question because I'm hoping you might be able to demonstrate it's on-topic

Comment: 1. What you wrote previously is nowhere stated in the link you provided. 2. Even here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask I can't see how my question is off-topic. 3. My question is about optimizing an EE tool (digital design specifically) for productivity. Like asking SO "how can I see all of my classes on [that] C++ IDE?". 4. The fact that ModelSim is not as popular as Eclipse, does not mean that my question is off-topic. 5. RTL simulation is a rather "close" field, in terms of software variety. So it's not about "a" tool, it's about "one of the 2 or 3 available" tools

Comment: If I vote to close the question, there are radio boxes that I can tick and one of them is the quote I wrote. Yes, I'm sympathetic to the fact that you can't see this so hopefully someone might be able to provide a link to that radio box option. I think that should be possible and if not I would say that's an anomaly that ought to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new Wave window with the following command:

```
view wave -new
```

The new windows have incremental name's, like "Wave1", "Wave2", .. but you can give a custom name using the `-title` option.

```
view wave -new -title Memory
```

To add signals to a specific Wave window, you specify the target with the `-window` option. For example:

```
add wave -position end -window Memory sim:/tb/address
```

Note that the Wave windows are paneled but you can move a panel out by dragging from the title. I don't know whether this can be scripted, though.

Answer (score 0):

view wave -new is not supported on PE, Intel FPGA or free license, you need a more expensive license

Answer (score 0):

Create new desktop and open Modelsim new window it worked for me